# Make a random integer that is perpetually changing?

Tags: c++, random, integer

How can I create a pseudo-randomized integer that is constantly changing?
This way, I could enter:

```
cout << randomInt << endl;
cout << randomInt << endl;
cout << randomInt << endl;
```

and the program would return something like:

```
45.7
564.89
1.64
```

(I'm not sure if any of this makes any sense.)

Comment: It's possible to do what you want, but I don't think is a good idea. Change of state should be explicit...

Comment: Those don't look like integers.

Comment: You could define `randomInt`, or preferably `RANDOM_INT`, as a macro that expands to call to a function that returns random numbers -- but your code would be much clearer if you just called the function directly. Why do you want to make it look like an object's value is changing?

Answer (score 8):

Create a class representing the Random number:

```
class Random {
};
```

Then overload `operator<<`:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Random& random) {
    return os << generate_random();
}
```

Use as:

```
int main() {
    Random random;
    std::cout << random; 
    std::cout << random; 
    std::cout << random; 
    return 0;
}
```

Obviously, you need to implement `generate_random`.

Comment: Small generic example how to overload the `<<` operator to output into streams: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z2f6c2k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Maybe it would be better to just implement the conversion operator to `int`?

Answer (score 5):

Using the new [C++11 pseudo-random number generation classes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random):

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(1, 6);
    for(int n=0; n<10; ++n)
        std::cout << dis(gen) << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The above simulates ten dice rolls.

If you want floating-point values instead of integers, use [`std::uniform_real_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution) instead of [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution).

Answer (score 4):

This is exactly what `std::rand` is for:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{    
    std::srand(static_cast<unsigned>(std::time(0))); // seed

    for (int i = 5; i--;) std::cout << std::rand() % 5 << '\n';

    // Output are random integers
}
```

***[Demo](http://ideone.com/2xeeLh)***

Comment: If I understand correctly, the _OP_ intention is to make the `rand()` calls implicit

Comment: Why is the `static_cast` needed? `time_t` is an arithmetic type; it will be implicitly converted to the parameter type `unsigned`.

Comment: @K-ballo: If I understand correctly, the OP's intention is a bad idea. Waiting for clarification.

Comment: @Keith Thompson: Yeap, yes it is... That was my first comment to his question

Answer (score 2):

Make a class with a single implicit conversion

```
class t { operator int() { return 42; } };

int main()
{
    t test; std::cout << t <<'\n';
    return test;
}
```

and of course whatever other members you want, just no other conversion operators.

Answer (score 1):

This will not play well with other random code...

```
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

struct RandomInt {
  RandomInt() {
    static bool initialized = (srand(std::time(0)), true);
  }
  operator int() {
    return std::rand();
  }
};
#include <iostream>
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& stream, RandomInt x ) {
  return stream << static_cast<int>(x);
}


int main() {
  RandomInt randomInt;
  std::cout << randomInt << "\n";
  std::cout << randomInt << "\n";
  std::cout << randomInt << "\n";
}
```

this is pretty much a bad idea.